# Run javascript function on one of many checkboxes changing

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onchange

I want to run a function when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. However, I have around 70 checkboxes. They are all within a div. How can I write one command that will react to any of them being changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events bubble up, so you can just attach an onchange handler to the div and use `e.target` to get the checkbox that changed. Here's a simple example of this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="two" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="three" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" />
</div>
```

​**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('checkbox-container').onchange = function(e){
    alert(e.target.name);
}​
```

[And here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/twGpZ/)

Comment: The change event may not bubble in all browsers, much better to use the click event. The above will also fail in browsers that support the IE event model, `e` will be undefined.

Comment: It's not just IE, the change event didn't bubble in most browsers until recently. HTML5 has changed many such things significantly, you need to code for browsers more than 12 months old.

Answer (score 1):

Based on ascii-time's answer, you can use event delegation. However, note that the change event doesn't bubble in all browsers and you must support the IE event model also, so use the click event and filter out the elements you don't want (or add alternative responses):

```
<div id="checkbox-container">
     <input type="checkbox" name="one">
     <input type="checkbox" name="two">
     <input type="checkbox" name="three">
     <input type="checkbox" name="pizza">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

  var container = document.getElementById('checkbox-container');

  if (container) {
    container.onclick = function(evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

      if (el && el.nodeType == 1 && el.type == 'checkbox') {
        alert(el.name + ' is ' + (el.checked? '':'not') + ' checked'); 
      }
    }
  }
}())

</script>
```

Note that the script must be below the container element. Just before the closing body tag is good.

Comment: +1 I was editing my answer, but you beat me to writing a better cross-browser answer.